# Roll two fair dice. Let X be the smaller of the pips showing on the two, and y the larger. Find the probability mass functions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Find the porbaility mass function of $Z~\overset{\text{def}}=~Y-X$.

Would it be the $$\sum_{y}^{} p(y)= 1$$ to find Y, in which we add all the probabilities of the pips being larger? Same goes for the X value.?

The problem i'm stuck on is how can I show which one is smaller and which one is bigger? Since if I get the smallest pips (1,1), then (1,2) would be considered bigger.

Comment: There are only $36$ possible rolls, just write them all down.  Then you'll have the answer and you can see if you can find better ways of getting to it.

Comment: $(1,1)(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3) (3,4) (3,5) (3,6)
(4,1) (4,2) (4,3) (4,4) (4,5) (4,6)
(5,1) (5,2) (5,3) (5,4) (5,5) (5,6)
(6,1) (6,2) (6,3) (6,4) (6,5) (6,6)$

Comment: Right.  So, what is $Z$ in each case?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you don't understand the definition of $Z$.  What it is:  you take your roll, $(a,b)$ and then you look at the result.  Say $a≤b$.  Then $Z=b-a$.  If, on the other hand, $a>b$ then $Z=a-b$.  Thus if you get $(2,3)$ then $Z=3-2=1$.

Comment: So I would have to do the Z case for every single roll?

Comment: Yes.  Well, there are faster ways to do it, but writing it out for each roll should take less than a minute.  Then, like I say, you'll know what the answer is and you can try to come up with more efficient ways to compute it.

Comment: Just to make sure I will get this: $0+1+2+3+4+5+1+0+1+2+3+4+2+1+0+1+2+3+3+2+1+0+1+2+4+3+2+1+0+1+5+4+3+2+1+0=70?$

Comment: Well, you don't mean to add them up.  The idea is to compute the probability of each case.  So...what is the probability that $Z=0$?  $Z=1$? and so on.

Comment: $P(Z=0)= \frac{1}{6}, P(Z=1)=\frac{5}{18}$ and so on?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.  To be clear:  while I'm sure there are some ways to do it more efficiently, the enumerative method is really not so terrible.  I suppose if these were hundred sided dice we'd need an alternate method.

Comment: True, so my answer would just be finding the probability of $Z(0,1,2,3,4,5)?$

Comment: Yes.  You just need to list those probabilities, which at this point you can simply read off.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.